# JSP with a HTML table and need to update the table

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a JSP with a table and inside the cells, I have buttons. My requirement is to fetch the cell contents from with in the same jsp for a period of some ms. Essentially the cell contents mean the button name and its value. Then I need to pass these values to another function to process. My jsp snippet is:

```html
<div> <table id="rooms" border="50" width="50%" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="10" style="float:center">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="abc" name="room" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="def" name="room" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="ghi" name="room" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="jkl" name="room" /></td>
                    </tr></tbody>


<%
response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);
        String[] room = request.getParameterValues("room");
          try{
              System.out.println(room[0]);
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("Error");
          }

        %>
```

I am getting Error because of null value. I can do this in javascript but I want only JSP code. Other forums I have seen jquery and ajax but still I prefer if there is a JSP only way.

I need help as to where I am doing this wrong. Any pointers?

Comment: "classic" (aka non-AJAX) way require <form .. in html, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp - the U can receive as parameters as expected. Refresh will not work

Comment: Miltiple objects with same name 'room' is probably wrong

Comment: if we cant use the same name, then should I use the type "submit" in getparameterValues?